# 3D Touch for Shortcuts Crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, 3dtouch

My app is a single-view NavigationController as a root view controller style app.  In it, I have a few different shortcut items for using 3D Touch.  I have them all set up in the Info.plist fine (I've done this before with a Tab Bar app and it worked fine), but it crashes every time an shortcut action is pressed.  Here is my the code used in AppDelegate in Obj-C.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performActionForShortcutItem:(UIApplicationShortcutItem *)shortcutItem completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL))completionHandler {
    UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *) self.theMainView.view;

    NSLog(@"%@", shortcutItem.type);
    if ([shortcutItem.type isEqualToString:@"com.316apps.Fritch.inviteFriends"]) {
        ImagePicker *vimeo= [[ImagePicker alloc] init];
        [nav pushViewController:vimeo animated:YES];

    }
    if ([shortcutItem.type isEqualToString:@"com.316apps.Fritch.viewAlerts"]) {

        NewsViewController *dvController8 = [[NewsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewsViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [nav pushViewController:dvController8 animated:YES];

    }
    if ([shortcutItem.type isEqualToString:@"com.316apps.Fritch.viewDirectory"]) {

        DirectoryViewController *dvController8 = [[DirectoryViewController alloc] init];
        [nav pushViewController:dvController8 animated:YES];


    }


}
```

Crash Log:

```
com.316apps.Fritch.viewDirectory
2017-01-19 22:44:23.305906 Fritch[3956:925348] -[UILayoutContainerView pushViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x101837530
2017-01-19 22:44:23.306768 Fritch[3956:925348] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILayoutContainerView pushViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Comment: Please add crash log.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `ImagePicker` is a viewController? The naming compared to the others suggest that it's a view. All your other controllers have the scheme: `someViewController` and not just `some`. If we are keeping with your convention, then it should be `ImagePickerViewController`. Hence why I'm asking, is that's a mistake?

Comment: @Brandon It is a view controller.  I am updating this app, and it used to be a tab bar controller.  While it was a tab bar controller, I was able to get the current tab, initialize it as the root view controller, and push whatever view I needed onto that.  These shortcuts worked fine on that, I just need to figure out what to do for it to work right on a UINavigationController as the root instead of tab.

Comment: @nynohu I have added the crash log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *) self.theMainView.view;
```

The reason of crashing is you are getting the `view`, not `ViewController`. So `self.theMainView.view` cannot convert to `UINavigationController`. If your self.theMainView is correct, fix that crash by using:

```
UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *) self.theMainView;
```

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, please remember to add crash log if your problem is  app crashing in the next time you want to ask.

Comment: I do have a somewhat related, somewhat different issue.  For the DirectoryViewController that comes up on shortcut, I have it password protected.  If the password hasn't been entered, it covers up that main view with a UIView that exists in the IB.  When I do the shortcut, I get the prompt for Touch ID, but it doesn't add that subview.  Here's how it is called:  `
        [self.navigationController.view addSubview:password];
        [self.navigationController.view bringSubviewToFront:password];` Is this due to self.navigationController not BEING the view?

Comment: In my opinion, you should get `ViewController`, not `navigationController` for `addSubView`. Could you try that?

Comment: I went ahead and made a new question over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41756488/uiview-not-added-when-coming-from-shortcut   I have tried self.view addSubview