# UIView Not Added When Coming From Shortcut

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

My app uses shortcuts with 3D Touch.  One such shortcut opens up a DirectoryViewController.  Now in that controller I use a quick check to see if the user has authenticated the password in a while.  If it hasn't, it does this:

```
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:password];
    [self.navigationController.view bringSubviewToFront:password];
```

When I simply click a button to go to that view, the password subview is added (which is a simple UIView located in the IB for the DirectoryViewController) and covers up the sensitive data on the TableView.

However, when I go to the Directory from the shortcut, I still get the prompt for Touch ID for password, but the UIView does not get added.  Thoughts?  Here is the AppDelegate code:

```
if ([shortcutItem.type isEqualToString:@"com.316apps.Fritch.viewDirectory"]) {

        DirectoryViewController *dvController8 = [[DirectoryViewController alloc] init];
        [nav pushViewController:dvController8 animated:YES];


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should get the exact `UIViewController` (in this case that is `DirectoryViewController`) from `self.navigationController`, and call `addSubView` with that `UIViewController`. Do not use `self.navigationController` for `addSubView`.

Comment: Pardon my lack of knowledge and lack of sleep starving my brain, but when the open view is DirectoryViewController and that is where the code is being run, how would that be written out?  I have tried self.view addSubview to no avail.  Also, the subview is added whenever I push DirectoryViewController onto the screen the normal way from a TableView, it just doesn't appear when doing shortcuts.

Comment: So I think the simplest way is: you can try to check and add `passwordView` directly in your `if ([shortcutItem.type isEqualToString:@"com.316apps.Fritch.viewDirectory"])`

Comment: I added a property for UIView in DirectoryViewController called _password and then on AppDelegate shortcut I made `if ([shortcutItem.type isEqualToString:@"com.316apps.Fritch.viewDirectory"]) {
        
        DirectoryViewController *dvController8 = [[DirectoryViewController alloc] init];
        [dvController8.view addSubview:dvController8._password];
        [dvController8.view bringSubviewToFront:dvController8._password];
        [nav pushViewController:dvController8 animated:YES];

        
    }`
But it still didn't work.  Did I do it in wrong order?

Comment: As you told *Also, the subview is added whenever I push DirectoryViewController onto the screen the normal way from a TableView, it just doesn't appear when doing shortcuts*. So you should add a flag for show/ not show passwordView and implement it on `DirectoryViewController viewDidLoad`. In `if ([shortcutItem.type isEqualToString:@"com.316apps.Fritch.viewDirectory"])` just only assign that flag YES or NO. I think it will work.

Comment: I figured it out...realized i only did init on the view controller instead of initWithNibName, so the password UIView was never getting initialized.  Changed it and it popped up right away